# How can I get RAM frequency from the OS X low-level terminal?

Tags: mac-osx, memory, terminal, frequency, recovery-services

How can I get RAM frequency from the OS X low-level terminal? Which comand can help in this situation?

Comment: What is a "low-level terminal"? If it's just a "regular" terminal, I would install and use `dmidecode`.

Answer (score 2):

The `system_profiler` is your friend,

From within Terminal you can type `man system_profiler` for more information.  Type `q` at any time to exit the man page.

To get all your memory information, you can use the following:

```
system_profiler SPMemoryDataType
```

If you want something formatted a little better, then you can pipe the output to `awk`, as seen here:

```
system_profiler SPMemoryDataType | awk '/Type:/ {type=$2} /Speed:/ {speed=$2; printf "%s-%s\n", type, speed}'
```

See also [awk/sed output from system_profiler on 10.6.8](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/25166/441550).

[image: screenshot of results]